# Fetching data is invoked twice in useffect, race condition between setState and await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await

Fetching data is invoked twice in useEffect, race condition between setState and await. Is there any other way to approach my problem?

Have tried with a cleanup function as well, and tried using a scoped variable with let, but with the same problem.

```
const [fetched, setFetched ] = useState(false)

const fetchData = async () => {
  // setGetCheck(true) if used here fetchingData is invoked once
  await fetchingData(); 
  setGetCheck(true) // This is where I want to set state
}

useEffect(() => {

  if(!fetched){
    fetchData();
  }
  
}, [fetchData]);
```

Comment: `fetchData` is not an `async` function and maybe because it is in strict mode the effect runs twice in dev server ....

Comment: fetchData function should be `async` function.

Comment: `fetchData` should not be a dependency of your effect! Since the function object is created anew on every render, the effect will run on every render. Did you mean to use `fetched` maybe?